gnuplot - Y-axis text too close to the plot
I have the following gnuplot script:
set grid

set style line 1 lc rgb '#a82828' pt 5
set xlabel "Entropy bucket"
set ylabel "Number of configurations"
set xrange [-1.0:1.1]
set yrange [0:35000000]
plot 'plot.dat' with points pointtype 5 pointsize 0.7 lc rgb "#a82828" t "$N = 50, S_{50} = 0.40$" at 0.4,0.93

set terminal cairolatex pdf size 14cm,10cm
set output 'plot.tex'
replot
exit

And plot.dat is like:
-1.00 0
-0.98 0
-0.96 0
-0.94 0
-0.92 0
-0.90 0
-0.88 0
-0.86 0
-0.84 0
-0.82 0
-0.80 0
-0.78 0
-0.76 0
-0.74 0
-0.72 0
-0.70 0
-0.68 0
-0.66 0
-0.64 0
-0.62 0
-0.60 0
-0.58 0
-0.56 0
-0.54 7
-0.52 14
-0.50 63
-0.48 112
-0.46 308
-0.44 504
-0.42 1092
-0.40 1680
-0.38 3150
-0.36 4620
-0.34 7854
-0.32 11088
-0.30 17556
-0.28 24024
-0.26 36603
-0.24 49140
-0.22 73332
-0.20 97272
-0.18 142597
-0.16 187040
-0.14 268380
-0.12 347368
-0.10 486038
-0.08 619416
-0.06 843738
-0.04 1057476
-0.02 1402632
0.00 1728384
0.02 2242017
0.04 2721264
0.06 3461339
0.08 4142768
0.10 5170200
0.12 6102334
0.14 7470141
0.16 8690676
0.18 10429643
0.20 11948244
0.22 14043204
0.24 15813336
0.26 18170642
0.28 20055420
0.30 22479017
0.32 24228316
0.34 26383329
0.36 27631982
0.38 29094919
0.40 29449056
0.42 29834847
0.44 29020706
0.46 28149786
0.48 26167960
0.50 24184440
0.52 21360024
0.54 18709054
0.56 15595776
0.58 12867744
0.60 10043754
0.62 7744968
0.64 5599020
0.66 3992758
0.68 2632700
0.70 1711983
0.72 1006552
0.74 584689
0.76 294630
0.78 147609
0.80 58772
0.82 23835
0.84 5992
0.86 1716
0.88 0
0.90 0
0.92 0
0.94 0
0.96 0
0.98 0
1.00 0

The two files above produce the following plot .tex:

As one can see, the text Number of configurations is too close to the actual plot. How can I move it a little to the left? I tried to google things up, yet failed to find anything relevant. Also, I have browsed my later gnuplot questions in an attempt to find that might have helped me; no luck.

All I needed was:
set ylabel "Number of configurations" offset -1.5,0

